# Nested For loop for initializing array of arrays for Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested

I have a very simple part of my program here that's having a problem... 
The elements in the array 'population' are also an array.. having 28 random numbers each 'temp' array that is being loaded to the array population. My problem is that the array 'population''s somehow have all the same arrays saved in it, it's like its being override every loop. Ive spent so much time in this very simple problem, is this some kind of bug?? The commented 'alert' is used to check the element 0 and 1 of the population. and somehow it's really being overriden every loop so every temp elements in the population array is all the same. Please help me..

```
var population[];
function init_population(){   
    temp = [];
    //Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<28;j++)
        temp[j] = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
        population[i]= temp;
    //alert("population[0] = " +population[0] +" and population[1] = " +population[1]);
    }
}

init_population();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `temp` array in the inner loop so you're not reusing the same array over and over:

```
var population = [];

function init_population() {   
    var temp, i, j;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        temp = [];
        for(j=0; j<28; j++) {
            temp[j] = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
        }
        population[i] = temp;
    }
}

init_population();
```

---

Since assigning the `temp` array into the `population` array only puts a reference to the `temp` array in, when you keep using the same `temp` array over and over again, you end up with references to the same `temp` array at each index of the `population` array.  If, instead, you create a new `temp` array in the inner loop, then each array in the `population` array will be different.

---

FYI, I also made some other corrections to your code to properly declare the variables `temp`, `i` and `j` as local variables so they aren't implicit global variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it really helped, but just to make me understand, i thought the temp array is just gonna be overridden since the j counter of the inner loop again is back to 0 once the outer loop iterates?

Comment: @WilmorHerald - you overwrite the values of the `temp` array, but you put a pointer to the same `temp` array in every element of the `population` array so every element in the `population` array is the same.  Instead, you have to create a new `temp` array with `temp = [];` inside the first loop so that each element of `population` contains a different array.  If you still don't understand, then you need to learn about assignment "by reference" and "by value" in javascript.  Google will be your friend.

Comment: Oh, now i understand clearly. Thank you so much, appreciate it. After i've understand it, i realized in a snap that my code was really idiotic. haha.. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's the same array.
You create it with `temp = []` and then assign it to each of the `population[i]` for i=0..9